# How to load a spritesheet in pixijs using a json inside the code?

Tags: json, pixi.js, texturepacker

I am trying to load a spritesheet from external json file but 1/1000 times it fails to load the spritesheet textures, so how can I ensure it won't fail by adding them from a json that is inside the code?

```
PIXI.loader
.add(path + "spritesheet.json")
.load(this.setup);
```